# Drop Down in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am automating one application and I have many drop downs in one of the webpage. All of the drop downs have a common class name also i can see no id associated with them.

I am able to select value from the first dropdown with no issues. Problem comes when i am trying to click second drop down. Due to common class name it is clicking first drop down only. Any solutions for that.

Code I have tried so far for first drop down:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div["class=Say class A']")).click();

TIA

Comment: Can u put the HTML . Also, you can try using //div["class=Say class A'][Position()=1] and so on , may be it will work.

Comment: @VinodKumar As per best practices, handle normal `DropDown` through `Select` Class and `option`. Incase of `Modal DropDown` proceed as intended. Let me know if your are still stuck. Update your research(code), HTML DOM & the error stack trace. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for your inputs. HTML code does not have "Select" class. Although i got my issue solved using dynamic xpath for different drop downs.

Comment: @VinodKumar When you say `HTML code does not have "Select" class` it clearly indicates you need to read docs on **`HTML`** and **`Selenium`** both. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div["class=Say class A'])[2]")).click();